# Quantile Mapping in R

Tags: r, quantile, error-correction

I am trying to bias correct PRECIS data for precipitation and temperature using different techniques for selecting the best one out of all.
I am stuck up with an error while using '`qmap`' package in R. It helped in giving results for an area averaged (2D Netcdf) `dataset` in the form of a 2D plot which also showed improved correlation when validated with the observation `dataset`. 
I am facing a problem when I am trying to run the same function over the entire 3D dataset.

On running the following:

```
test=fitQmap(Observation_data,Model_data, method = 
"PTF",transfun="scale",cost="RSS",wett.day=TRUE)
```

I am encountered with this error:

```
 "Error in x[!nas] : object of type 'S4' is not subsettable"
```

Kindly help me out in getting rid of the error as I am a beginner in handling climate datests in R. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the same command, just run a loop over all the latitude and longitude dimension.

Am assuming your time dimension is 3rd.

## First create an empty matrix with Nan values

```
OUTPUT<-array(NA,c(length(lon),length(lat),length(time)))

    for (i in 1:length(lat))
    {
     for (j in 1:length(lon))
         {
    Observation<-Observation_data[i,j,]
    Model<-Model_data[i,j,]
    test=fitQmap(Observation,Model, method = "PTF",transfun="scale",cost="RSS",wett.day=TRUE)
    OUTPUT[i,j,]<- doQmapDIST(Test_data$Model[i,j,],test)
     rm(test)
      }
    }
```